How come my JVM does not shutdown when using Google Cloud Firestore BulkWriter?
I'm trying to implement the BulkWriter from Google Cloud Firestore in Kotlin.
When I create documents individually (without the BulkWriter) my application works normally. However, when using the BulkWriter instead everything works as expected but the JVM won't shutdown at the end.
To reproduce the issue I've written a small test file:
import com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreOptions


fun main() {
    val firestore = FirestoreOptions.newBuilder()
        .setEmulatorHost("localhost:8768")
        .setProjectId("bulkwritertest")
        .build().service

// Using BulkWriter to create documents. Documents are created but JVM won't shutdown using this
    firestore.bulkWriter().use { bulk ->
        repeat(10) { index ->
            bulk.create(
                firestore.collection("bulk").document("test-" + index),
                mapOf("name" to "test " + index)
            )
        }
    }
    
// Not using BulkWriter to create documents. Documents are created and JVM will shutdown at the end
// Disable the BulkWriter block and enable this block to test
//    repeat(10) { index ->
//        firestore.collection("bulk").document("test-" + index)
//            .create(mapOf("name" to "test " + index)).get()
//    }
    
// In all cases the application will print all documents created (i.e. the BulkWriter is actually finished and closed)
    firestore.collection("bulk").listDocuments()
        .forEach { document ->
            println(document.get().get().data)
        }

    firestore.close()
}

In all cases (BulkWriter or no BulkWriter) this function will get to print all the documents at the end. So there is no blocking operation within the use block of the BulkWriter and the BulkWriter must've been closed at this point.
Since there is no other code, I'd expect the JVM to shutdown at this point (which it does when using the code in comments that is not using the BulkWriter)
Edit: Even after adding firestore.close() at the end or putting it all in a firestore.use { ... } block does not help.
I can't find good documentation or samples on the use of BulkWriter with Java/Kotlin. Are there mechanics I should be aware about? Am I doing something wrong on the usage?

Dunno if it's related, but if you're inserting a lot of stuff, there's a chance the last batch isn't being written, causing the close() method to wait forever for the last batch to be written.
Just filed a bug here since we were seeing it as well!
Here's where you're probably getting stuck:
// From BulkWriter.java:

  /**
   * Commits all enqueued writes and marks the BulkWriter instance as closed.
   *
   * <p>After calling `close()`, calling any method will return an error. Any retries scheduled with
   * `addWriteErrorListener()` will be run before `close()` completes.
   *
   * <p>This method completes when there are no more pending writes. Calling this method will send
   * all requests.
   */
  public void close() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ApiFuture<Void> flushFuture;
    synchronized (lock) {
      flushFuture = flushLocked();
      closed = true;
    }
    flushFuture.get();
  }

